# How do I know which image version is installed on a specific instance of an Azure VMSS?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have an Azure VMSS (Virtual Machine Scale Set) with a few instances, linked to an "image gallery". The VMSS is configured in such a way that it is supposed to always choose the latest version of a specific image from the image gallery.

How and where can I see, which version of the image is installed on a specific instance?

Answer (score 6):

If the image gallery is configured to install the *latest* image on new instances, the image version can potentially vary between instances. The actually *installed* version of an image is stored in the `storageProfile.imageReference.exactVersion` property of the vmss object.

**Listing the *installed* image version for a specific machine in an existing scale set:**

```
az vmss show --resource-group "<resource group name>" \
  --subscription "<subscription name>" \
  --name <vmss name> \
  --instance-id <instance id> \
  --query storageProfile.imageReference.exactVersion
```

The reply matches the version number defined in the image gallery:

```
"2021.06.1782103"
```

If the instance id is not known, it is possible to **get all instance ids of an existing scale set**:

```
az vmss list-instances --resource-group "<resource group name>" \
  --subscription "<subscription name>" \
  --name <vmss name> \
  --query [].instanceId
```

```
[
  "1141",
  "1142",
  "1143"
]
```

To further simplify things, one could **list the *installed* image version for each machine in an existing scale set**. This allows, for example, to see if all instances are at the same version or one is left behind:

```
az vmss list-instances --resource-group "<resource group name>" \
  --subscription "<subscription name>" \
  --name <vmss name> \
  --query [].storageProfile.imageReference.exactVersion
```

In an example with 3 instances the reply may indicate that two machines are on the later version (...03), and one machine is still on an older version of the image (...02):

```
[
  "2021.06.1782102",
  "2021.06.1782103",
  "2021.06.1782103"
]
```

Finally, to combine this one can also **query for instanceId and installed image version at the same time**:

```
az vmss list-instances --resource-group "<resource group name>" --subscription "<subscription name>" --name <vmss name> --query "[].[instanceId,storageProfile.imageReference.exactVersion]"
[
  [
    "1141",
    "2021.06.1782102"
  ],
  [
    "1142",
    "2021.06.1782103"
  ],
  [
    "1143",
    "2021.06.1782103"
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the exect version of image reference for one specfic instance by using the [Get-AzVmssVM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/get-azvmssvm?view=azps-5.9.0) cmdlet with the following sytax:

```
(Get-AzVmssVM -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Name $ScaleSetName -InstanceId $instanceId).StorageProfile.ImageReference
```

[image]